# Array of Objects Java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm in my first JAVA class and I got this far with my code. I'm trying to use the for loop to print off the properties.

*This is the main.*

```
public class PostOffice {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MailBox[] PostOffice = new MailBox[5];

        PostOffice [0] = MailBox(123,"Bob");
        PostOffice [1] = MailBox(456,"John";
        PostOffice [2] = MailBox(789,"Mark");
        PostOffice [3] = MailBox(200,"Bill");
        PostOffice [4] = MailBox(444,"Sam"); 

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            System.out.println (PostOffice[i]. getMailboxNumber());
            System.out.println (PostOffice[i].getOwnerName());  
        }
    }
}

public class MailBox {
    private int mailboxNumber;
    private String owerName;
    private boolean mailDelivered;
    public static  int totalNumberOFMailboxes;

    public MailBox(){
    }
    public MailBox(int theNumber, String theOwner){
        mailboxNumber = theNumber;
        owerName = theOwner;
    }
    public int getMailboxNumber(){
       return mailboxNumber;
    }
    public String getOwnerName(){
        return owerName;
    }
    public void setOwnerName(String someName){
        owerName = someName; 
    }
    public  boolean getMailDelivered(){
        return mailDelivered;
    }
    public void setMailDelivered(boolean ismail){
        mailDelivered = ismail; 
    }
}
```

I don't think Im setting the properties in the array correct.My complier keeps giving me this error

error: cannot find symbol
PostOffice [0] = MailBox(123,"Bob");
symbol:   method MailBox(int,String)
location: class PostOffice

Comment: It is highly recommended to figure out the name of the language you're trying to write code in. Java is not Javascript.

Comment: You are using the same name `PostOffice` for the name of a class and also for a method-local variable. This is highly discouraged, and you should follow standard Java naming conventions (initial caps for class names, initial lower-case for variables).

Answer (score 4):

You are not creating a new object, try the following

```
PostOffice [0] = new MailBox(123,"Bob");
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create object in Java using `new` operator. So, the following line:

```
PostOffice [0] = MailBox(123,"Bob");
PostOffice [1] = MailBox(456,"John";
PostOffice [2] = MailBox(789,"Mark");
PostOffice [3] = MailBox(200,"Bill");
PostOffice [4] = MailBox(444,"Sam");
```

Need to changed to:

```
PostOffice [0] = new MailBox(123,"Bob");
PostOffice [1] = new MailBox(456,"John";
PostOffice [2] = new MailBox(789,"Mark");
PostOffice [3] = new MailBox(200,"Bill");
PostOffice [4] = new MailBox(444,"Sam");
```

Answer (score 0):

Rookie mistake, don't worry I got you!

Whenever you create a new object, make sure to use the `new` keyword. That way, space is allocated for your new object. So put this in replacement of creating your object.

```
PostOffice [0] = new MailBox(123,"Bob");
```

Oh, and when you're creating your other MailBox objects, make sure to add the `new` keyword as well ;-)

Happy Coding!